# How to reduce the screen size of google map in ios application

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

In my application I have included google maps API but the problem is, it is occupying the entire screen but I dont want it occupy entire screen as I have other UI controls on the same screen. I  have my code pasted below.

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:12.9699 longitude:77.6499 zoom:6];
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0, 10, 25) camera: camera];
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
NSLog(@"User's location: %@", mapView_.myLocation);
UIEdgeInsets mapInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(100.0,10.0,  10.0, 300.0);
mapView_.padding = mapInsets;
self.view = mapView_;

GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(12.9699,77.6499);
marker.title = @"BANGALORE";
marker.snippet = @"IndraNagar";
marker.map = mapView_;
```

Answer (score 1):

self.view = mapView_; **instead of this add below code**

```
UIView * MApBaseView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];// add your frame size here
    [self.view addSubview:MApBaseView];
    [MApBaseView addSubview: mapView_];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace  `marker.map = mapView_;` as  `[self.view addSubview:mapView_];`

See the below code

```
 GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
                                                        longitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude
                                                             zoom:16];

    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-44) camera:camera];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:mapView_];
```

Comment: @user3663506 please accept the answer if it solve your problem so it could help for the others

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code, it work for me:

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latitude
                                                            longitude:longitude
                                                                 zoom:14];
    mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:mapViewContent.frame camera:camera];
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    mapView.delegate = self;
    [mapViewContent addSubview:mapView];
```

`mapViewContent` is your view custom.